# iOS - Some points in UITableView cell are not selectable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that when you choose a cell another ViewController will be opened. But some points in my cell, when tap on them nothing happens.
My TableView cell contains a photo, and two  TextView, when i tap on textViews nothing happens.
even when I set them selectable and editable the problem exists.
how can i fix this problem??

Comment: Please post code/storyboards how your table view is configured

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)             {
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "allNotesToShowNoteSeg", sender: notes[indexPath.row])
        
                                  }

Comment: i dunno how to send a photo :( to show table view cell elements @Alistra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
cell.textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

UIImageViews have this property disabled by default, while UITextView has it enabled by default.
That's why pressing imageview passes the tap properly, while textView doesn't.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it shouldn't be. You want an editable UITextView on tap, while at the same time, you want didSelect to be called?

Comment: oooh thank u so much...i disabled them and it's ok now @Nebojsa Nadj

Comment: your're right i mistook :))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES
```

And If you using StoryBoard or xib, make sure your textview is the subview of cell's contentview not cell.

Comment: it's enabled and my textview are in content view @Chokwah

Comment: @Dr.Arash when you click cell , func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) not be called ? Do you set tableview delegate = self?

Comment: it will be called. my problem is that when i tap text views it doesnt call ( but when i tap on image it works)